# How Can i Write This Firebase Rule?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here is my Data Structure

```
"Users": {
  "userId" : {
    "email" : "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "points" : 50,
    "subscriber" : false
  }
}
```

Here's the current rule i specified

```
"User":{
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
    ".write": "auth != null"
   }
}
```

With that Rule ^^ it allows me to write to the `"User"` reference but i what i want is

```
"User":{
  "$uid": {
     ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
     ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
   }
}
```

but this rule ^^ does not allow me to write to `"User"` reference, which means i cannot even create a reference talkless of updating it.

I tried to use

```
"User":{
".write": "auth != null" // << -- this line overrode the entire children
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
   }
}
```

In essense am looking for a way to for Authenticated users write to `"User"` reference but Only Authenticated Users with Matching `uid`can read and update a `uid` node.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no difference between `===` and `==` in Firebase Database security rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i know !== and != is the same, then === and == too ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: Thanks @josedlujan, i will try it now

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for the edit. You've been helpful on most firebase related questions

Comment: @josedlujan what does that rule equate to? i ran it on its simulator i couldn't read it _"Simulated read denied"_

Comment: There are no `".read"` expressions in the snippet, so reads are disallowed. Your question was about writing, so I assume that's why Jose focused on solely those rules.

Comment: yes, i only want authenticated users with matching uid to be able to read and write but i won't be able to write to the _Users_  reference because i can't specify a different rule there

Comment: am looking for a way around that, as specified in my question, such that a new Authenticated user can write to the user's reference but cannot read or update other uid except a matching one

Comment: `"User":{
".write": "auth != null" // <<--- Interferes with descendants rules
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
   }
}`

Comment: looking for a way to do that ^^ without that rule interfering with my _uid_ descendants rule